# $.fileName will not work in script in OS X and Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm using a `.jsx`-script in Adobe Illustrator, which stores its preferences in an JSON file generated in the basic script folder within the Adobe program folder.

But it does not work in my case, the file will not be created. The reason is, that the script does actually not get a path where to build it, so no file is being created.

I gave Illustrator full hard drive privileges already, but the script will not show the script path. On a different machine it's the same behavior, but I know the script will work for most other users. Even running the script from desktop does not work.

```
app.path
```

will give the path to Adobe Illustrator, the script is placed within that folder. I can read and write within the script subfolder of Adobe Illustrator.

```
var scriptPath = (new File($.fileName)).path
```

will tell "",  with alert just an empty field

```
var scriptName = (new File($.fileName))
```

will throw `/3` with alert (scriptName). It will always be `/3`, that's kind of wired.

It's the same, when I run the script from Desktop. Any idea, why the script will not get it's path? No one in the community had an idea so far (other than permissions, but as mentioned above, they do not account for this issue as `app.path` works) ...

Comment: This ```$.fileName``` is not supported in Adobe Illustrator scripting on MacOS x. So, try use ```$.global``` to store the path of the script when its run. Store the path of the script like ```$.global.myScriptPath = $.fileName;```, then use the path later in the script ```var scriptPath = $.global.myScriptPath;```

Comment: `$.fileName` works just fine for me (macOS Monterey, Illustrator CC 2023)

Comment: @YuriKhristich I know that it runs for many others. One idea is, that it will only run in English OS and English version of Illustrator. Currently both of them are German in my case ...

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I did not understand your idea. When `$.fileName `is not supported, how should it work with `$.global.myScriptPath = $.fileName;`

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation yes, I tried 'en_US' locale. It's a valuable clarification.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I cannot store the path, if I do not get it with the script in first place ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.fileName` will not work if the script will be started from different Scripts Panel plugins, but will work when started from Illustrator scripting menu.

There is a bug in these Scripts Panels, which breaks all lines of code with `$.fileName`. Refer to the discussion at Adobe Community [Adobe Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/filename-will-not-work-in-script-in-os-x/m-p/14299776#M390998)

Comment: Just in case. You can run a script in Illustrator if you drag and drop the jsx-file into Illustrator. On the Windows I made Illustrator to open all jsx-files by default, so it runs scripts via double click on a jsx-file, or even via Win+R and type the jsx file name.

Comment: @YuriKhristich There is a package for Sublime, where you can start Illustrator scripts from. This one helped me, to figure out the issue. Maybe you use sublime, too, than this could be helpful tool for you, too: https://github.com/rendertom/Sublime-Text-Adobe-Script-Runner

Comment: Great. I'm using VS Code in the same way.